# Using integers as values with a Typescript Enum?

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

When using integers as values in a Typescript enum it seems they all turn in to keys.  Here's an example:

```
enum Precision {
  ONE = 1,
  TWO = 2
}

const keys = Object.keys(Precision)
console.log(keys) //["1", "2", "ONE", "TWO"]
```

Also if we try to get the values like this:

```
let v:number[] = Object.keys(Precision).map(key => Precision[key])

console.log(v)  //["ONE", "TWO", 1, 2]
```

Is this a bug?  Is it possible to use integer values and get the expected semantics?  When using string values the above examples turn out OK.  Here's a complete demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-enum-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how `enum` works in typescript. It creates an object which will map the string keys to numbers and numbers back to those keys ([Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings))

> **Reverse mappings**
>
> In addition to creating an object with property names for members, numeric enums members also get a reverse mapping from enum values to enum names.

This how the enum is transpiled to javascript ([Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBACgTsAxgSwM7IPYigbwLABQUUA8gHICiUAvFAIwA0hxAKgOok1QBMhAvoSA))

```
var Precision;
(function (Precision) {
    Precision[Precision["ONE"] = 1] = "ONE";
    Precision[Precision["TWO"] = 2] = "TWO";
})(Precision || (Precision = {}));
```

That is a fancy way of writing:

```js
var Precision = {}

Precision["ONE"] = 1
Precision["TWO"] = 2

Precision[1] = "ONE"
Precision[2] = "TWO"
```

This makes it easy for you to convert the string value to number and numeric value to string using the bracket notation.

Do note that **only numeric enum values** get this Reverse mapping. If you create

```
enum Precision {
  ONE = "1 value",
  TWO = 2
}
```

It gets converted to:

```
var Precision = {};

Precision["ONE"] = "1 value"
Precision["TWO"] = 2

Precision[2] = "TWO";
```

without the `"1 value"` key in the object

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to work with only the keys (Left side of the equal sign)?

Comment: @Ole `Object.values(Precision).filter(v => !Number.isFinite(v) )`

Comment: Nice - Like it!